# php - get file type from contents

Tags: php, image, mime-types

I'm on the lookout for a function which gets the file type from the contents of a file.

ie.

```
public function wideImage( $width, $height, $cropped, $file )
{
    $cacheForInMinues = 15;
    $cacheName = md5( $file . $width . $height . $cropped );
    if ( Cache::has( "images.{$cacheName}" ) )
    {
        $image = Cache::get( "images.{$cacheName}" );
        // get_file_type_from_contents( $image );
    }
    else
    {
        ....
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the header of the content.
Take a look at this : http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html

But I don't know if there is a already made function to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/fileinfo);

```
<?php
function get_file_type_from_contents($image) {
    $finfo = new finfo;
    $fileInfo = $finfo->file($image, FILEINFO_MIME);
    return $fileInfo;
}
```

Comment: Warning

This function has been deprecated as the PECL extension Fileinfo provides the same functionality (and more) in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks @Dragon, I have forgot about that